# Jenkins Google Login Plugin - Matrix Security

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, google-oauth, google-signin

I was able to configure the Google Login Plugin on Jenkins 2.138.2 and I am able to successfully authenticate against our Gsuite domain. Currently all authenticated users of my domain have the ability to do anything within jenkins. Of those 70 users, only about 30 should have the ability to access jenkins and of those 30 only 5 should have full admin rights.

What is the best way of allowing matrix based security when using the Google Login Plugin? Is there any way I can specify permissions based on GSuite groups?

[image]

Comment: This is currently not supported by the Google Login Plugin, check this issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28010

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Role-based Authorization Strategy plugin (https://plugins.jenkins.io/role-strategy) along with the google login plugin and set different roles to users based on their email from within jenkins. Could be good as a workaround until https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-28010 is released